# Making for loop more idiomatic

Tags: python

I want to make the first for loop more pythonic, so how can I use only one variable instead of 2?:

```
    #Split input file into lines using LF as separator
    program_lines1 = input_file.split("\n", "")

    #Delete CR at end of lines if present
    program_lines2 = ""
    for line in program_lines1:
        program_lines2.append(line.replace("\r"))

    #Delete 3rd and last lines of file which are never requested
    del program_lines2[2]
    del program_lines2[-1]

    #Delete all p2 lines
    for line in range(len(program_lines2)):
        program_lines2.remove("p2")
```

I'm thinking enumerate might be part of the answer.  Also, is there anyhting more pythonic for the last for loop?.  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is `input_file`? If you're actually reading in from a source file somewhere I would think you should do this from inside of a `with open(path, 'r') as f` loop. But it depends on how you're getting input_file.

Comment: Massage an input file into lines with some characters and lines removed.  Input file is terminated by either CRLF or LF.  The split takes care of the LF.  Comments should explain the rest.  Input file is just a text string as far as this part of the program is concerned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you code:

```
for line in range(len(program_lines2)):
        program_lines2.remove("p2")
```

can be replaced with

```
program_lines2 = [line for line in program_lines2 if line != 'p2']
```

Same situation with first variable - code

```
for line in program_lines1:
    program_lines2.append(line.replace("\r"))
```

can be replaced with

```
program_lines1 = [line.replace("\r") for line in program_lines1]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! That definitely helps, thanks.  I didn't know I could use the for loop that way

Comment: @dpetican You can google for "list comprehension". It's fancy way to work with sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines? Took the liberty of not using "for" loops whatsoever.

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()  # Split file into lines
    lines = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), lines))  # Clear LF's
    lines = list(filter(lambda x: x != "p2", lines))  # Remove all 'p2'
    lines.pop(2)  # Remove third line
    lines.pop(-1)  # Remove last one
```

Comment: Yes! Even more idiomatic.  I like it, but @Absolut answer gets accepted because its closer to the original problem.  However, I will use your solution in my program.  Thanks.

Comment: True! His is closer, considering the fors and such. Glad to help!

Comment: I think using `list()` with `map()/filter()` is totaly unpythonic

Comment: Maybe, but I'm going to pull a Dilbert as the only one in this shop who knows python and program in some job security using the "unpythonic" way LOL.  I'm still learning python so both solutions are very educational as I program lots of similar variants.  Thanks you both.

Comment: @Absolut Yeah, and I'll be the first to admit that I don't know any other way to (easily) convert from the generator that map() and filter() return back to a simple list. (addendum: this applies to Py3. In 2, as far as I remember, they return lists)